# ¿como usar la librería address en angular?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular

Así que estoy intentando saber mi ip con la ayuda de la librería address:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/address

la importo de esta manera, en el component

`import * as address from 'address';`

e intento obtener la ip con el método ip();

`console.log(address.ip());`

Pero al momento de compilar con ng serve, sale unos errores, que no encuentra librerías de node:"child_process, fs, os".

> ERROR in ./node_modules/address/lib/address.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'D:\Documents\Proyectos\Java\JavaSpringBoot\spring-boot-frontend-apirest\node_modules\address\lib' ERROR in ./node_modules/address/lib/address.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Documents\Proyectos\Java\JavaSpringBoot\spring-boot-frontend-apirest\node_modules\address\lib' ERROR in ./node_modules/address/lib/address.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'D:\Documents\Proyectos\Java\JavaSpringBoot\spring-boot-frontend-apirest\node_modules\address\lib'

¿Alguien sabe el motivo del problema o no se puede usar esta librería en angular?..
muchas gracias por su atención ☺.

Comment: Estás usando webpack?

Answer (score 0):

efectivamente esa es una librería para aplicaciones del lado del servidor.

Si lo que quieres es obtener tu IP publica, puedes intentar usando la siguiente librería [public-ip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/public-ip) la cual funciona en navegadores.

```sh
$ npm install public-ip --save
```

```
import * as publicIp  from 'public-ip';

@Component({...})
class AppComponent {
constructor() {
    publicIp.v4().then((ip)=>{
      console.log(ip);
    })
  }
}
```